# How to import data into DB from an text file?

Tags: postgresql, phppgadmin

How can I copy data from a text file to a postgresql database?

I tried this but it doesnt work:

`COPY data FROM '/home/pi/Downloads/data.tsv' DELIMITER ' \ tab' 

COPY data FROM '/home/pi/Downloads/data.tsv' DELIMITER '\t' 

COPY data FROM '/home/pi/Downloads/data.tsv' DELIMITER E'\t'`

I Also Tried to convert it into .csv and run this:

`COPY data FROM '/home/pi/Downloads/data.csv' ( FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER(';') , HEADER);`

I want to import these file into my database: ("title.basics.tsv.gz")
https://datasets.imdbws.com/

My table looks like:

data 
- Title_ID        -- integer
- tconst          -- text
- title           -- text
- primaryTitle    -- text
- originalTitle   -- text
- isAdult         -- boolean
- startYear       -- text
- endYear         -- text
- runtimeMinutes  -- text
- genre           -- text

Comment: What is the error message your are getting ?

Comment: SQL-Fehler:

FEHLER:  Syntaxfehler bei »FROM«
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (COPY data FROM '/home/pi/Down... 
                                                 
In der Anweisung:
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM (COPY data FROM '/home/pi/Downloads/data.tsv' DELIMITER '\t') AS sub